# How to test if cookie contains pattern VCL (Varnish)

Tags: varnish, cookies

How can I test if a cookie starts with `SESS*` in the Varnish config file. I want all requests to hit the server if this cookie is set. Is it a regular regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, just use a regex in vcl_recv.  Something like:

```
if (req.http.Cookie ~ "(^|;\s*)SESS") {
    return(pass);
}
```

Comment: I already have something like: `if (req.http.Cookie ~ "(VARNISH|DRUPAL_UID)") {
        return (pass);
    }`. Should I just add this afterwards?

Comment: Yeah that'll work.